# Show that $f(t)=(a_{1}t^{2}+b_{1}t+c_{1}, a_{2}t^{2}+b_{2}t+c_{2}, a_{3}t^{2}+b_{3}t+c_{3})$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is a plane curve.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, curves, parametrization

A curve $f:I \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is said to be flat, if there is a plane $\beta=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:ax+by+cz=d\}$ such that $f(t) \in \beta$, for all $t \in I$. Show that $f(t)=(a_{1}t^{2}+b_{1}t+c_{1}, a_{2}t^{2}+b_{2}t+c_{2}, a_{3}t^{2}+b_{3}t+c_{3})$,  $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is a plane curve.

Comment: Hint: Do you know how to find the torsion of a parametric curve? If the torsion is zero everywhere, it is a plane curve.

Comment: @JoshuaWang No, I don't know how to find the torsion of a parametric curve, how would that be?

Comment: @hardmath I do not understand

Comment: $$\tau = \frac{(\textbf{f}''\times\textbf{f}')\cdot\textbf{f}'''}{\vert\vert\textbf{f}'\times\textbf{f}''\vert\vert^{2}}$$

Comment: In this case, there is probably a better method than trying to prove that the torsion is $0$.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, you are right I was wrong, you must go t no x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\vec{f}=\vec{c}+t\,\vec{b}+t^2 \, \vec{a}$ with constant vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}.$  Take $\vec{k} = \vec{a} \times \vec{b}$ to be the cross product of $\vec{b},\vec{a},$  so that $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{a} = 0$ and
$\vec{k} \cdot \vec{b} = 0.$  Then
$$(\vec{f}-\vec{c}) \cdot \vec{k} = 0  $$ is your plane

Comment: I do not see clearly what $(\vec{f}-\vec{c}) \vec{k}=0$

Answer (score 2):

Torsion for a general parametric curve can be [computed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve#Alternative_description) using a determinant of the curve's first, second and third derivatives:
$$\tau=\frac{\det(r',r'',r''')}{\|r'×r''\|^2}$$
Since all components of this curve are quadratic, the third derivative $r'''$ is the zero vector, so the determinant and hence the torsion are zero.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing.